# Algorithm Not Properly Killing Go Pieces When Air To Bottom Right

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I've created an algorithm to determine which pieces have been killed in a game of Go. For my algorithm, pieces are stored in a 2D array of rows and columns (from `0`-`8`, as I am using a 9x9 board). Each piece is also an array, where:

- `piece[0]` is the color of the piece, either `"empty"`, `"black"`, or `"white"`.
- `piece[1]` is irrelevant.
- `piece[2]` is a boolean of whether or not it has liberty (initially set to `true` if an empty square and `false` if there is a piece there).
- `piece[3]` is whether or not it has been iterated over in the algorithm yet. All pieces start with this as `true`.

Here is the algorithm for discerning which pieces have liberty:

```
let oldBoard = 0;
while (board != oldBoard) {
    oldBoard = board;
    for (let row = 0; row < 9; row++) {
        for (let col = 0; col < 9; col++) {
            if (board[row][col][2] && !board[row][col][3]) {
                board[row][col][3] = true;
                if (row != 0 && (board[row][col][0] == "empty" || board[row][col][0] == board[row-1][col][0])) { board[row-1][col][2] = true; }
                if (row != 8 && (board[row][col][0] == "empty" || board[row][col][0] == board[row+1][col][0])) { board[row+1][col][2] = true; }
                if (col != 0 && (board[row][col][0] == "empty" || board[row][col][0] == board[row][col-1][0])) { board[row][col-1][2] = true; }
                if (col != 8 && (board[row][col][0] == "empty" || board[row][col][0] == board[row][col+1][0])) { board[row][col+1][2] = true; }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Afterwards, it removes all pieces that are marked as not having liberty (`piece[2] == false`).

Everything works fine, unless the air spaces are to the bottom/right. For instance, if you put down this configuration:

[image]

Then the X-ed out piece will be captured, which it shouldn't be. But, if you put down this configuration:

[image]

Then no piece will be captured, which is the expected result.

As best as I can tell from my investigations of the bug, it seems to be that any piece that was marked as having liberty from a piece to its bottom or right is unable to give any adjacent pieces liberty.

You can find the full repository [here](https://github.com/fin444/rego).

Comment: This approach is not working properly for real go games. After placing a stone, one (or even more) group of each color could be surrounded, but then the one(s) of the player who didn't place the stone are removed. Also removals can only happen when placing a stone, so you don't need to iterate the whole board. It is illegal to place a suicide stone, a stone that would be immediately killed (alone or together with all other stones of the groups it is connecting to) unless it kills an enemy group / single stone (but then you have to take ko into account).

Comment: Sorry for forgetting to specify this: determining if moves are suicide and only killing enemy pieces are also determined afterwards, but those aren't what's causing the issue because they don't have the power to remove liberty from pieces that should have it (the issue here). Also, due to custom modifications to the rules of this version of Go, ko is legal.

Comment: There are few problems here. One is that the code does not care if the surrounding piece is white or black. Another is the fact that captured stones are not determined by the liberty of a single stone, but instead of a group of stones

Answer (score 0):

I might be late on this one, but here's my idea.

As I commented, you should look at the stones as a group, instead of looking at it individually.

@maraca 's comment was very helpful. Since adjacent stones to the updated stone is affected, you could check all four adjacent pieces from the updated stone, then check each of those stones' adjacent stones and so on... until it ends. The function can look something like this.

```
function isGroupAlive(x, y) {
  let stack = [];
  let alive = false;

  const check = (x, y) => {
    stack.push([x, y].toString());
    let cell = board[x][y];

    if (x !== 0 && board[x-1][y][0] === null) alive = true;
    else if (x !== 0 && board[x-1][y][0] === cell[0] && stack.includes([x-1, y].toString)) check(x-1, y);

    if (x !== size-1 && board[x+1][y][0] === null) alive = true;
    else if (x !== size-1 && board[x+1][y][0] === cell[0] && stack.includes([x+1, y].toString)) check(x+1, y);

    if (y !== 0 && board[x][y-1][0] === null) alive = true;
    else if (y !== 0 && board[x][y-1][0] === cell[0] && stack.includes([x, y-1].toString)) check(x, y-1);

    if (y !== size-1 && board[x][y+1][0] === null) alive = true;
    else if (y !== size-1 && board[x][y+1][0] === cell[0] && stack.includes([x, y+1].toString)) check(x, y+1);
  }

  check(x, y);
  return alive;
}
```

I used a stack to keep track of already iterated stones' coordinates, but you could do something else too.